# How to SUM the COUNT list in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Here you can see I want to count all page hits, then score the sum. There is no error at all until I add in   'COUNT(hits.type = 'PAGE') AS PV_yo' at which point it complains about ' hits.page.pageTitle,' not being grouped. I am new to this and stumped..

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  pageTitle,
  contentGroup1,
  CASE
      WHEN SUM(pv_yo)<=400 THEN 1 * 0.4
      WHEN  SUM(pv_yo) <=800 THEN 2 * 0.4
      WHEN  SUM(pv_yo) <=1625 THEN 3 * 0.4
      WHEN  SUM(pv_yo) <=3250 THEN 4* 0.4
      WHEN  SUM(pv_yo)  <=6500 THEN 5 * 0.4
      WHEN  SUM(pv_yo) <=13000 THEN 6 * 0.4
      WHEN  SUM(pv_yo) <=26000 THEN 7 * 0.4
      WHEN  SUM(pv_yo) <=52000 THEN 8 * 0.4
      WHEN  SUM(pv_yo)<=104000 THEN 9 * 0.4
      WHEN  SUM(pv_yo)>104000 THEN 10 * 0.4
    ELSE
    0
  END
     AS PV_score,

FROM 
 ( SELECT
    hits.page.pageTitle,
    hits.contentGroup.contentGroup1,
    COUNT(hits.type = 'PAGE') AS PV_yo

  FROM
    `datasetname.ga_sessions_*` AS GA,
    UNNEST(GA.hits) AS hits,
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) AS CD
  WHERE
    CD.index = 3
    AND hits.contentGroup.contentGroup1 != '(not set)' )

GROUP BY
  pageTitle,
  contentGroup1
ORDER BY
  AVG_PV DESC
```

Comment: Are you using BigQuery or something?  It's very useful to specify exactly which dialect of SQL you're using in the tags (Just using `sql` isn't descriptive enough).

Comment: Also, if you move the `)` at the end of your sub-query to the start of the next line, it makes it easier to see.  It then becomes clear that your subquery doesn't have a `GROUP BY` at all, yet you're using `COUNT()`.  Are you able to explain what you're trying to do, why you're using an aggregate without grouping, and what you think should happen?  Then we can help by explaining the correct syntax / pattern to achieve your goals.  *(Using example data, particularly for the behaviour of the sub-query, often helps demonstrate expected/required behaviour.)*

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie, yes I am using bigQuery. Truthfully i have been learning SQL for about 4 days so I have no doubt I am making really stupid mistakes here. What I am attempting to do is count total page 'hits' and then score the sum of these hits to use in an overall engagement metric I am developing. So as COUNT is an aggregate, I need to have a group in the sub query? That would be a start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need aggregation, so I assume the subquery should be:

```
SELECT hits.page.pageTitle,
       hits.contentGroup.contentGroup1,
       COUNTIF(hits.type = 'PAGE') AS PV_yo
FROM `datasetname.ga_sessions_*` AS GA CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(GA.hits) AS hits CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) AS CD
WHERE CD.index = 3 AND
      hits.contentGroup.contentGroup1 <> '(not set)' 
GROUP BY hits.page.pageTitle,
         hits.contentGroup.contentGroup1;
```

Note that I changed the `COUNT()` to `COUNTIF()` -- under the assumption that you are using BigQuery.  In any case, `COUNT()` is uninteresting because that counts the number of non-`NULL` values rather than the number of `true` values.